# Create a class in an Android project

Tags: java, android, class, kotlin

My question might not be useful but I really need to know why a lot of people creat new classes (Right-click, create new, class) but not use code to create a new class (for example: `class task(var title:String, var time:String)`).

Comment: These are two different ways to the same goal, I don't think this is a question, which belongs to this website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets says you very simple app with MainActivity.class
you want to add a new class.

you can do it in a separate file (right-click, create a new class) or in the MainActivity.class declare the class, for example

```
public class Car {
  private String carModel;
  private String carColor;

  //constructor
  public Car (String carModel, String carColor) {
    this.carColor = carColor;
    this.carModel = carModel;
 }

 //add setters and getters, methods and other stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen creating classes like that. Seems like you've mixed up functions with classes. Can you provide us any source where this way of creating classes is used?

Comment: They create classes like this ([photo](https://imgur.com/a/7uKcm)) but not with code like this ([photo](https://imgur.com/a/FwFrE))